# Calculating percentiles of a raster (TRMM DATA)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.2

I have a set of raster (floating point) i.e A daily rainfall intensity data for a year, now i need to select and group these raster in to various percentile categories,
Above 90th percentile, 50-90, 10-50, below 10.
how to achieve this using ArcGIS 10.2 ?

Answer (score 4):

If you are doing percentiles (10 of) then you can use [Slice](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z000000ss000000), otherwise if you need more control (perhaps one range is 20%, or 5%) then [Reclassify by Table](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Reclass_by_Table/009z000000sq000000/) will serve you better.

If you have lots of data to accumulate (I seem to remember a question like this for Africa very recently) you will need to accumulate using the [Raster Calculator](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z000000z7000000) to a sum of the rainfall, then if you need to divide by the number of inputs for an average.

Comment: Can u guide me through it as I'm totally new on this., how to achieve it using raster calculator, some examples.

Comment: Here is a link to the documentation http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z000000zn000000 What you want to do is add a bunch of them in ArcMap and *search* for raster calculator and then execute it from the search window which brings up a dialog, then you double click each layer in the left window and in between press the plus button. This will add the values into an output raster. If you have python experience it may be easier to build the dialog but that's essentially all there is to it.

Comment: I got it on how to use Raster Calculator many thanks, How to run Percentiles in it for the following "A daily rainfall intensity data for a year, now i need to select and group these raster in to various percentile categories, Above 90th percentile, 50-90, 10-50, below 10"

Comment: Here's a good post that shows the syntax, it's in python but the tool is the same http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/95027/multiple-conditional-statement-with-in-a-con-tool/95028#95028 using the con tool http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z00000005000000.htm you will need three con statements to get your results.. first less than 10, second less than 50 then less than 90.